# ActivityNotFoundException when trying to start activity from an intent returned by Action.PICK_ACTIVITY

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application that associates "gestures" with activities (like Dolphin Browser do with urls). What I want to do is to allow the users to select an activity with Action.PICK_ACTIVITY :

```
    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        data.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, data);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_ACTIVITY);
...
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACTIVITY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Gesture gesture = new Gesture();
        gesture.intent = data;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GestureEditorActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("com.example.gesture.Gesture",gesture.toByteArray());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And then, when the user draw the associated gesture, I start the activity :

```
Intent intent = GestureList.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getIntentForGesture(gesture);//intent corresponds to data in onActivityResult method
    if(intent != null)
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.unrecognized_gesture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I got an ActivityNotFoundException :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN dat=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;component=com.android.calculator2/.Calculator;end }
```

Here is my getIntentForGesture method :

```
public Intent getIntentForGesture(Gesture gesture)
{

    float bestDist = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Gesture bestGesture = null;
    for(Gesture g:this)
    {
        float dist = gesture.distance(g);
        if(dist < bestDist)
        {
            bestDist = dist;
            bestGesture = g;
        }
    }

    if(bestGesture != null)
        return bestGesture.intent;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Sorry for my broken English and thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: it seems problem is in your manifest xml. have you add the activities in manifest properly?

Comment: Yes I did but the activity I am trying to start is from another application

Comment: Where is the code for `getIntentForGesture(gesture);`? Your mistake is probably in that function not returning the proper intent.

Comment: what about checking before trying to `startActivity(intent)` if there is actually an Activity to handle that Intent, i answer how in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778300/androidactivitynotfoundexception/16778593#16778593

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to your intent

```
Intent intent = GestureList.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getIntentForGesture(gesture);//intent corresponds to data in onActivityResult method
if (intent != null) {
    try {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.unrecognized_gesture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Up to where I understand, this solution will only be valid if he is calling the `startactivity()` from outside an activity. He doesn't really tell us. If it's something like a service, then you are correct.

Comment: I get `ActivityNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type`. Maybe better to catch `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: I am sorry, @LuisA.Florit, where do you get that exception? `ActivityNotFoundException` is already handled for `startActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

The Calculator activity can't be found. Probably a problem in your manifest file, so you can try:

Option #1:

Check everything is well written. The error message states:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN dat=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;component=**com.android.calculator2/.Calculator**;end }
```

That slash `/` may be the error.

OPTION #2:

The key in your case is that you are trying to open an activity from another package (in this particular gesture, the calculator), so you could try checking if you can launch the calculator app like this:

```
Intent calcInt = new Intent(); 
calcInt.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); 
startActivity(calcInt);
```

If the calculator doesn't launch with this simple code, then I would bet the device doesn't have the default calculator installed.

OPTION #3:

Post your Android Manifest file so we can check it.